# Add multiple image upload in shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm new in shopify. Please can anybody help me for adding a custom multiple image upload section in settings_schema.json

Here is my code -

```
{
    "name": "Banner",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Image Options"
      },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "use_img",
        "label": "Use Custom Banner?"
      },
      {
        "type": "image",
        "id": "start_page_bg.jpg",
        "label": "Custom Banner",
        "max-width": 1200,
        "max-height": 1200
      },
      {
        "type": "paragraph",
        "content": "Recommend the optimal width and height for your banner here."
      }
    ]
  }
```

That was for single image upload. I want to upload multiple images for banner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify doens't have a multiply field option at the moment.

Recently Shopify included a Sections option, where there is an option for multiply images, but this will be true only for the homepage ( or where you include the `content_for_index` tag).

There are a few ways you can workaround this issue:

1) Create multiply fields with id's image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg etc.. and loop them with a for loop. But it will be required for them to always be visible in the settings page.

2) Create a navigation field and create a navigation with Web Address type links, where the web address will point to the image. You will loop the links of that navigation and use them as images.

3) Create a blog field and create a separate blog, where you will be able to create post using that blog, where each post can use a featured image. You will loop the post from that category and you will have access to the images.

Comment: I'm using a custom shopify theme. How will I add sections for slideshow? Please send me the code

Comment: understanding this is a very old post, but a question regarding the first method (creating multiple fields), would these fields be mandatory?

Comment: @Amjo There is no "required" fields in the sections and there is no way to create one. So the user can leave them blank and if the liquid logic check if they are empty or not there will be no problem to leave them blank.